# Scrapy combine yields to same package

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape a number of pages for different years and add them to the same package that should get in the pipeline. This is what i've got:

```
def parse_main_page(self, response):
    dropdown = response.xpath(".//form[@name='somenname']")
    if dropdown:
        options = dropdown.xpath("./select//option")
        for option in options:
            text = option.xpath("./text()").get()
            value = option.xpath("./@value").get()
            url = self.compose_fin_link(value, pkg)
            req= scrapy.Request(url, callback= self.parse_option)
            req.meta['method'] = 'FINSIT'
            req.meta['item'] = pkg
            req.meta['year'] = text
            yield req

def parse_option(self, response):

    pkg = response.meta['item']
    year = response.meta['year']
    pkg[year] = dict()
    main = response.xpath(".//div[@id = 'main']//table//tr")
    for row in main:
        texts = row.xpath(".//font/text()").getall()
        texts = [x.replace('.','') for x in texts]
        if len(texts) > 1:
            pkg[year][texts[0]] = texts[1]
        else:
            pass
    yield pkg
```

If the `dropdown` has 3 options for example, in my pipeline i will get 3 packages, each yielded by `parse_option`. I need to yield `only 1 package containing all three options` not 3 packages for each option.

Outside of `scrapy` i would do something like this:

```
def parse_main_page(self, response):
    pkg = dict()
    for option in options:
        pkg[year] = self.parse_option(url)
    yield pkg

def parse_option(self, response):

    ##Do something here
    return option_content
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options how to do it. The first one is to collect the URLs into a `meta` attribute in the `parse_main_page` method and then in the `parse_option` method pop one URL at a time and accumulate the results into another `meta` key, e.g. `item`. Something along these lines:

```
def parse_main_page(self, response):
    dropdown = response.xpath(".//form[@name='somenname']")
    if dropdown:
        options = []
        for option in dropdown.xpath("./select//option"):
            text = option.xpath("./text()").get()
            value = option.xpath("./@value").get()
            url = self.compose_fin_link(value, pkg)
            options.append({
                'url': url,
                'method': 'FINSIT',
                'item': pkg,
                'year': text
            })
        next_option = options.pop()
        url = next_option.pop('url')
        meta = {
            'data': next_option,
            'options': options,
            'item': {}  # we will collect the data for each individual option to this
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_option, meta=meta)

def parse_option(self, response):
    # parsing logic ommited as it stays mostly the same
    # ...
    item = response.meta['item']
    current_options = response.meta['data']
    # `current_option` contains `item` and `year` values, use it to populate an intermediate `item` dict
    options = response.meta['options']  # other options that need to get processed
    if options:
        next_option = options.pop()
        url = next_option.pop('url')
        meta = {
            'data': next_option,
            'options': options,
            'item': item  # contains data from all options processed so far
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_option, meta=meta)
    else:
        # no more options to process, our `item` is finalized
        yield item
```

It's not tested as you didn't provide all the necessary information, but should work in principle.

Another option is to use [scrapy-inline-requests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) as extracting the data from dropdown URLs is the final stage. Check out [the example](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests/blob/master/example/stackoverflow.py) provided in the repo. Basically, in your case you would go like this:

```
@inline_requests
def parse_main_page(self, response):
    dropdown = response.xpath(".//form[@name='somenname']")
    if dropdown:
        item = {}
        for option in dropdown.xpath("./select//option"):
            text = option.xpath("./text()").get()
            value = option.xpath("./@value").get()
            url = self.compose_fin_link(value, pkg)
            response = yield scrapy.Request(url)
            # ...
            # process the response as in `parse_option` method and collect results in `item`
            # ...
        yield item
```